# How to completely remove wicd from 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager, uninstall, wicd

I had issues with WiFi so I removed Network Manager.

I booted Windows OS (dual booting Windows 7 and 12.04) to download  `wicd 1.7.2.4`. Extracted it and  installed. However, `wcid` worked properly with Wired Connection but could not connect to WiFi. So, I re-installed Network Manager which works properly now, and `wicd` connects to WiFi too.

As soon as I disconnect from Network Manager, `wicd` connects only to wired. At this point, I wanted to remove `wicd` but `apt-get` returns `no wicd installed`, can't see it in Synaptic or Software Center, but only in Applications list under Dash home.

Of course `wcid` icon shows connections, and  resulting connected, so my system shows both applets for `wicd` and `network manager` in the top panel. When running `dpkg` commands, *wicd is not listed* as installed package.

Any suggestion how to remove `wicd`? Consider that I started with Ubuntu just few months ago so my knowledge base is limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I also had problems with Wicd + NetworkManager, it had to be decided which one will disappear from the OS, as it seems both interfaces do a sloppy job when it comes to deal with dependencies and side effects.

First I decided to remove Wicd, and that should match your question (then I tried Wicd without NM, but that's another story...).

Normally, if installed from a package (apt-get), the line

```
sudo apt-get purge wicd
```

should be enough. If not, and installed from the source, there is a `uninstall.sh` in `wicd-dir/` source code dir that should fix the uninstallation. If not...

1. the theory wants that editing

   /etc/default/wicd

and set `START_DAEMON=no` would be enough of a job to just stop the process and family from starting. But it's not enough. So... when a program is tied to several places that don't rely on a single config file, I remove it completely:  (it's also linked to my own gnome configuration, and yours may vary)

2. ensure the init program does not run

That's basically in `/etc/rcX.d`. All the `S20wicd` can be renamed `K00wicd` automatically, thanks to a script like [rcconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/rcconf.8.html).

And now remove the crumbs...

3. move the desktop autostart stuff

Something like

```
mv /etc/xdg/autostart/wicd-tray.desktop /etc/xdg/wicd-tray.desktop.donotstart
```

4. dbus

Similar to the above

```
mv /etc/dbus-1/system.d/wicd.conf /etc/dbus-1/wicd.conf.donotstart
```

And reboot, wicd should be quieter.

Again depending on your settings, the files could be somewhere else in `/etc`.
Do a `find /etc -iname "*wicd*"` to find where they're likely to sit.

Answer (score 4):

have you installed it from source? you can't use synaptic or software center to remove wicd then.

By the way, you should look for a startup script, to remove wicd from startup. Then you will not need to uninstall, it won't get started if you remove it. Check `/etc/rc5.d` and `/etc/xdg/autostart` for entries. (I assume you boot to gui)

Comment: Thanks g_kaya, ur reply made me think and i come to a solution, i removed it from start-up applications, then installed wicd and uninstalled it using terminal, then manually removed files i had downloaded. NM works nice now :) and  wicd  completely removed :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad you solved your problem.